# correlation with logarithmic transformation

Tags: regression, correlation, data-transformation

I have a dataset of 2.000.000 projects. Each project is defined by its size and the number of active developers.

After applying a logarithmic transformation on the project size, I've plotted the data.
It seems to me that the number of active developers decreases when the project size goes up. When I try to apply Spearman's correlation rank, I find only little evidence of it (0.09520886)

I tried to use linear regression: `lm(size ~ active developers)` (in R), but I got negative results:

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   41.672      2.871  14.513   <2e-16 ***
colls         18.381     11.034   1.666   0.0957
Residual standard error: 4089 on 2126091 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  1.305e-06, Adjusted R-squared:  8.351e-07 
F-statistic: 2.775 on 1 and 2126091 DF,  p-value: 0.09572
```

Then I tried to use a negative binomial regression `glm.nb(commits ~ colls)`, but I got negative results again:

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
   (Intercept)  3.73200    0.04862   76.76   <2e-16 ***
   colls        0.32318    0.18683    1.73   0.0837 . 

Null deviance: 2168.2  on 2126092  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2164.6  on 2126091  degrees of freedom
AIC: 41924708

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  0.0002086134 
      Std. Err.:  7.43e-08 

2 x log-likelihood:  -41924701.8870000020 
qchisq(0.95, 2126091) =  2129484
```

Which method I should use to get more insights about the relation between these two variables?

[image]

I add the plot of mean log against file[,4]
[image]

I add the plot of mean reciprocal against number of active developers
[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems like an updated version of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93335/grouped-data-vs-ungrouped-data. If it is, please consider deleting the older version. As far as the present question goes, two million values is a ridiculously large data set which enables very precise examination of the relationships. Why don't you start by plotting median (or mean) log against `file[,4]` and *look* at the relationship?  No statistical test is needed (at least for `file[,4]` less than 5) because there is so much data.

Comment: thanks for answering @whuber, which test I should use for 5,6,7, knowing that for 6 I have only 6 projects and for 7 only 1? Should I remove 6 and 7 from the analysis? Is it valid to measure the strength of the correlation on the average log values of the project sizes against the number of active developers?

Comment: Your data look like they might be even better analyzed in terms of their reciprocals, rather than their logarithms: that would produce a more linear relationship and (more importantly) looks like it might make the residuals more symmetric and constant across $x$ values. It's more important at this stage to characterize the data for 0 through 4. Later you can check whether an extrapolation of this characterization would be consistent with the (very limited) data for 5, 6, and 7. Incidentally, you could work with a stratified sample of 0.1%  of the data and get fine results with less work.

Comment: Plotting the mean reciprocals is somewhat helpful, but of even greater importance is describing the *variation* of the reciprocal data around those means. How the magnitude of the typical variation changes with x-coordinate provides useful clues about how to express the data and how to describe their relationships. But regardless of how you analyze them, you will find significant lack of fit, for the sole reason that you have so much data. You might be best off just summarizing the distributions of the data for each x-value.

Comment: Thanks for all these clarifications. if I go for a stratified sample, how can I know if the random samples are representative of the corresponding stratum? Should I use a non-parametric test like Mann–Whitney U test? For extrapolation do you mean using a regression model or there are other techniques that could come in handy?

Comment: I apologize for repeating myself, but *you do not need to do tests.* Practically anything you test for with a dataset this size will be "significant." There's a "so what" factor to this. What you want to focus on is describing and, where possible, understanding the patterns in the data set, not testing whether you have enough data to detect them! As far as working with a sample goes, that's what randomization was invented for: just take a random selection of, say, 1000 results for each value of $x$ (or all of them where fewer than 1000 are available).